# How to upgrade from OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 to macOS Sierra 10.14.3

Tags: software-update

i was downloaded the macOSUpd10.14.3.dmg file and run it i get the error message "This software is not supported on your system."

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're attempting to get something done, however it's vital you provide us with sufficient details to assist you. As the question is written, we're missing a lot of relevant information. As a minimum, can you please edit your question to include the exact model of Mac you're using, as well as *how* you downloaded the .dmg file you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the 'delta' Update file from Mojave 10.14.2 to 10.14.3, not the full upgrade installer.

You can only get the full installer through the App Store, & only if your machine can run Mojave.

If your machine cannot run Mojave, then see [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275) for suggestions.